# Implementing callbacks from GStreamer for Mono/Gtk# code in Linux

Tags: c#, callback, mono, gstreamer, gtk#

I'm playing around with Mono under Debian and implementing a simple media player (based on the [Gstreamer SDK tutorial #5](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+5%3A+GUI+toolkit+integration)).

Unlike that tutorial, I'm using c#/Gtk# and attempting to do my own Interop bindings to use the GStreamer libraries.

Now, I can call simple functions in the GStreamer and other libraries, using things like:

```
[DllImport("libc.so")]
    public static extern int getpid ();
[DllImport("libgstreamer-1.0.so")]
    public static extern bool gst_uri_is_valid (String uri);
```

This all works wonderfully. However, I'm not sure what to do with callback functions, needed to connect signals to my own code. Specifically, the `g_signal_connect_data()` function requires a couple of callback addresses for delivering information to my code.

If the code were C rather than C#, there'd be no issue, I'd simply use `&function` to pass as a callback address. However, given the code is in C#, what is the best process (or any process, really) to allow the callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out C# interoperability actually provides delegates for just this purpose, and you can get function pointers for those delegates for dealing with unmanaged code.

As an example, let's consider the contrived case where you have some C code for calling back to C# in order to add two numbers together.

We'll provide one function in C which will receive the callback address and the two numbers:

```
typedef int (callbackFn)(int, int);
int addViaCallBack (callbackFn fn, int a, int b) {
    return fn (a, b);
}
```

You can make a library out of this file with the commands:

```
gcc -fpic -c -o addViaCallback.o  addViaCallback.c
gcc -shared  -o addViaCallback.so addViaCallback.o
```

and you will then have something you can call from C# and which will call back *into* C# to do its work. On the C# side, it basically consists of:

- creating a `DllImport` binding so you can call the C function.
- creating the C# callback function for that C function to call back to.
- creating a delegate and then function pointer for that callback.
- calling the C function with the function pointer and numbers.

The following C# code shows how to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace callbacktest {
    class MainClass {
        [DllImport("addViaCallback.so",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int addViaCallback (IntPtr cb, int n1, int n2);

        public static int CallbackFn (int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }

        public delegate int AddViaCallbackDelegate (int a, int b);

        public static void Main (string[] args) {
            IntPtr addViaCallbackFp = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(
                new AddViaCallbackDelegate (MainClass.CallbackFn));

            for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
                for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
                    int c = addViaCallback (addViaCallbackFp, a, b);
                    Console.WriteLine (a + " + " + b + " = " + c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The C# code calls the C function, passing the C# function callback and the two numbers to add. That C function then calls the C# callback function with the two numbers. The callback function adds the numbers and returns the result to the C function which, in turn, returns it to C#<sup>(1)</sup>.

```
         C#                            C
|------------------|         |--------------------|
| Calls C function |         |                    |
| with (callback,  |         |                    |
| n1, n2).         |___      |                    |
|                  |   \     |                    |
|                  |    \___\|                    |
|                  |        /| Receives from C#   |
|                  |         | callback, n1, n2)  |
|                  |         | then calls back to |
|                  |      ___| C# with (n1, n2).  |
|                  |     /   |                    |
|                  |/___/    |                    |
| Receives (n1,    |\        |                    |
| n2), adds them,  |         |                    |
| and returns sum. |___      |                    |
|                  |   \     |                    |
|                  |    \___\|                    |
|                  |        /| Receives sum,      |
|                  |      ___| passes it back.    |
|                  |     /   |                    |
|                  |/___/    |                    |
| Receives sum.    |\        |                    |
|------------------|         |--------------------|
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Never mind the fact that it would have been *infinitely* simply to just add the numbers in C# in the first place. This is only meant to provide a simple example - GStreamer is *far* more complex that adding two numbers together.

Comment: I recommend you to use GStreamerSharp: https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp